# Offline Sqlite sync between two devices

Tags: java, android, sqlite, bluetooth, nfc

I developed an android App which uses a local Sqlite Db on the Devices. Now I want to sync the database with the database on a second device. The devices are never connect to the internet. Is there an "easy" way to synchronize the db via bluetooth or nfc? So far I've only heard about the online synchronization with MySQL?

Thanks

Comment: NFC would be far too slow and that use of NFC is deprecated, use Bluetooth or WiFi Direct

Comment: Ok thank you, I chose WiFi Direct and now I have a simple P2P connection between my 2 devices. But I only found solutions to share Strings (like a chat app) or files. Is there a simple way to send objects that contain for example 4 Strings?